# SQL SELECT INSERT INTO Generate Unique Id

Tags: sql, database, select, insert, sybase

I'm attempting to select a table of data and insert this data into another file with similar column names (it's essentially duplicate data). Current syntax as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, id2, col1, col2)
SELECT similiarId, similiarId2, similiarCol1, similiarCol2  
FROM TABLE2
```

The problem I have is generating unique key fields (declared as integers) for the newly inserted records. I can't use table2's key's as table1 has existing data and will error on duplicate key values.

I cannot change the table schema and these are custom id columns not generated automatically by the DB.

Comment: is it important to keep original values of keys?

Comment: dont insert similarid from table2 and let table table1 generate new id for the rows

Comment: is the ID in table1 a custom ID ? If not, you can use IDENTITY on the ID and it will automatically create the ID for you.

Comment: you can use autoincrement for table1 and don't insert similarId in table1 as rs said.

Comment: Can't you just add an identity column to table1 and make the new column the primary key? Then you just do the insert without the new primary key column and the identity auto-generates your keys.

Comment: Some demo data highlighting the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Does table1 have an auto-increment on its id field? If so, can you lose similiarId from the insert and let the auto-increment take care of unique keys?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id2, col1, col2) SELECT similiarId2, similiarCol1, similiarCol2
FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: This is a custom id, not auto incremented / generated by the database.

Answer (score 10):

As per you requirement you need to do you query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, id2, col1, col2)
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ASC )) 
+ (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE1) AS similiarId
, similiarId2, similiarCol1, similiarCol2  
FROM TABLE2
```

What have I done here:
Added [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) which will start from 1 so also added [`MAX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) function for ID of destination table.

#### For better explanation [*See this SQLFiddle.*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b827/15)

Answer (score 5):

Im not sure if I understad you correctly: 
You want to copy all data from TABLE2 but be sure that TABLE2.similiarId is not alredy in TABLE1.id, maybe this is solution for your problem:

```
DECLARE @idmax INT
SELECT @idmax = MAX(id) FROM TABLE1

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, id2, col1, col2)
SELECT similiarId + @idmax, similiarId2, similiarCol1, similiarCol2  
FROM TABLE2
```

Now insert will not fail because of primary key violation because every inserted id will be greater then id witch was alredy there.

Comment: +1. I would suggest this as well as long as it's not done frequently on a large table (performance issue w/ `max`) and it's okay to change the similiarID "key" (no referential problems).  Otherwise, they might need to [roll their own sequence](http://www.isug.com/Sybase_FAQ/ASE/section6.2.html#homegrown) or use a temp table with an identity.

Answer (score 3):

If the id field is defined as auto-id and you leave it out of the insert statement, then sql will generate unique id's from the available pool.

Comment: This is not an auto-id field.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server we have the function ROW_NUMBER, and if I have understood you correctly the following code will do what you need:

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, id2, col1, col2)
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY similiarId2 ASC )) + 6 AS similiarId, 
similiarId2, similiarCol1, similiarCol2  
    FROM TABLE2
```

ROW_NUMBER will bring the number of each row, and you can add a "magic value" to it to make those values different from the current max ID of TABLE1. Let's say your current max ID is 6, then adding 6 to each result of ROW_NUMBER will give you 7, 8, 9, and so on. This way you won't have the same values for the TABLE1's primary key.

I have asked Google and it said to me that Sybase has the function ROW_NUMBER too (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/ug-olap-s-51258147.html), so I think you can try it.

Comment: Careful with this one...they haven't specified that they're using Sybase SQLAnywhere, they've only said 'Sybase', so there's a pretty good chance that they're referring to Sybase ASE, which does not have the `ROW_NUMBER` function to my knowledge?

Comment: @sybkar, thanks for you comment. In this case I recommend the approach pointed by Jarek Bielicki, or using a temporary table with identity column as a intermediary table if user1464435 wants to guarantee its sequential new ids.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make an identical table why not simply use (quick and dirty) Select INTO method ?

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE2
FROM TABLE1
```

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make the table1 ID IDENTITY if it is not a custom id.

or

Create new primary key in table1 and make it IDENTITY, and you can keep the previous IDs in the same format (but not primary key).

Comment: Updating DB schema not an option here, need a function or sql query to do this as it's a custom id.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to add an additional column on Table2 for Table1.Id. This way you keep both sets of Keys.

(If you are busy with a data merge, retaining Table1.Id may be important for any foreign keys which may still reference Table1.Id - you will then need to 'fix up' foreign keys in tables referencing Table1.Id, which now need to reference the applicable key in table 2).

Comment: Updating DB schema not an option here, need a function or sql query to do this as it's a custom id.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your 2nd table keep similar values as in 1st table , then donot apply `auto increment` on 2nd table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large range, and want easy fast make and don't care about ID:

Example wit CONCAT

```
INSERT INTO session(SELECT CONCAT("3000", id) as id, cookieid FROM `session2`)
```

but you can using also REPLACE