# How to create int IDs during set insert in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert, table-valued-parameters

I am exploring the use of table valued parameters in  stored procedures to do multiple inserts in a single call to the database.

The table value parameter contains information that, more or less, reflects the definition of the table I want to insert into. It is only missing the ID column.

If I have the following table definition:

```
Create Table Product
(
     ProductID int,
     ProductName varchar(100),
     ProductDesc varchar(4000),
     ProductCost int
)
```

Type definition:

```
Create Type ProductTable as Table
(
    ProductName varchar(100),
    ProductDesc varchar(4000),
    ProductCost int
)
```

and stored procedure definition:

```
Create Procedure usp_Product_Insert
    @Products ProductTable READONLY
AS
    INSERT Product
    (
        ProductID,
        ProductName,
        ProductDesc,
        ProductCost
    )
    SELECT
        (Select ISNULL(Max(ProductID),0) + 1 From Product),
        P.ProductName,
        P.ProductDesc,
        P.ProductCost
    FROM
        @Products P
```

How do I alter what I have to insert unique id's if there is more than one set of data in my parameter?

Right now, if I run the following statement

```
Truncate Table Product
Declare @Products ProductTable
Insert @Products Values ('Playstation', 'Game Console', 300)
exec usp_Product_InsertUpdate_WithOutput @Products
```

through the stored procedure with no previous records in the table, I get

```
ProductID   ProductName ProductDesc ProductCost
1           Playstation     Game Console    300
```

But if I run more than one record through

```
Truncate Table Product
Declare @Products ProductTable
Insert @Products Values
('Playstation', 'Game Console', 300),
('Xbox', 'Game Console', 200),
('Wii', 'Game Console', 150)
exec usp_Product_InsertUpdate_WithOutput @Products
```

I get

```
ProductID   ProductDesc     ProductDesc ProductCost
1           Playstation     Game Console    300
1           Xbox            Game Console    200
1           Wii             Game Console    150
```

What I would like to see is

```
ProductID   ProductDesc     ProductDesc ProductCost
1           Playstation     Game Console    300
2           Xbox            Game Console    200
3           Wii             Game Console    150
```

**How can I accomplish this efficiently without using identity?**

Comment: Using `IDENTITY` is the **best and only reliable way** to do this. Why are you explicitly excluding this approach?

Comment: The business is *wrong*

Comment: @DeveloperKlin That's not a Business Requirement since a **business** requirement would not specify what you can use in the database.  There is no **business** need to use a specific data type, there is a **developer** somewhere between the DB and the business that is interpreting something.

Comment: You are right, I misused the term. Regardless, these are the guidelines I have to work with. I am obviously aware of the benefits of identity

Comment: You can't accomplish this efficiently without using identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. And should not even try.

Business define business keys.

Developers define [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

What you want is a surrogate key, so use an `IDENTITY` column.

If your business defines surrogate keys, then your duty is to teach them they should not do so.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088430/sql-select-insert-into-generate-unique-id) provided by [hims056](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056):

The stored procedure would be rewritten as follows:

```
Create Procedure usp_Product_Insert
    @Products ProductTable READONLY
AS
    INSERT Product
    (
        ProductID,
        ProductName,
        ProductDesc,
        ProductCost
    )
    SELECT
        (ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY ProductID ASC )) + (Select ISNULL(Max(ProductID),0) From Product),
        P.ProductName,
        P.ProductDesc,
        P.ProductCost
    FROM
        @Products P
```

Comment: This provides no concurrency... which is exactly why you should use an identity column instead of rolling your own solution and getting it wrong.